# Lattice modifier deforms object as soon as an object is selected

Tags: modifiers

I have an object I would like to deform with a lattice modifier. I have a lattice prepared that entirely encloses my mesh. I select the modifier for my mesh, but in the modifier window, as soon as I select the lattice in the `Object` dropdown, it deforms the mesh in an undesirable way.

Any idea why it gets deformed?

Here is the lattice:

[image: the lattice]

the mesh:
[image: the mesh]

and the mesh deformed as soon as I select a lattice in the `object` dropdown: 
[image: deformed_mesh]

I am using blender 2.69. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome Charlie :) It's always a good idea to use latest blender version to make sure this is not a fixed bug. You can upload the blend here: www.pasteall.org/blend and add it to the question, if you think this could help to solve your issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Changes to the lattice while in edit mode will be used to deform the mesh. This applies even if you alter the lattice before linking with the modifier.

Also selecting and scaling all points in edit mode, like you would with a mesh object, will add an odd out of proportion scaling effect while scaling the lattice in object mode.

To prevent this you need to scale the lattice in object mode to get it to the starting position that you want before making any changes in edit mode.

Comment: Magnificent. This was it exactly!

Comment: I noticed this as well after some experiments. Would be great though if the scale in edit mode could be undone with a click of a button. Or even a reset to initial state button would be helpful.

Comment: Also worth pointing out - after re-scaling the lattice in 'object' mode, *do not* 'Apply Scale' as that will have the same effect as if you'd manipulated it in Edit mode.

Comment: @RichSedman Your answer is exactly what helped me. Simple and important, Thanks!