# How do you freeze or reset a lattice?

Tags: modifiers

I have a complex object and I created a lattice around it. Before adding the lattice modifier I manipulated the lattice points so that it perfectly encompasses my object. Then when I add the modifier, my object gets translated and scaled down significantly. I am guessing this is because I scaled the lattice down to match it to the object size, and moved/rotated it to get it into place. I tried pressing Ctrl+A to Apply Location, Rotation, and Scale, but this did nothing but change the object translation (though it did not correct it; just made it wrong in another way.)

Here's my object with the un-attached lattice:
[image]

Then when I add the lattice modifier using this lattice:
[image]

Then I tried Ctrl+A to "Apply" the location, rotation, and scale of the lattice and the object:
[image]

And finally I tried positioning the origin of both the lattice and the object to the same spot (center of tire):
[image]

I am out of ideas. I saw this thread where someone ran into the same problem but the answer to his explicit question does not solve the implicit problem: [Lattice modifier deforms object as soon as an object is selected](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26499/lattice-modifier-deforms-object-as-soon-as-an-object-is-selected)
I hope it is not that a lattice has to always start as a perfect cube.

EDIT: I even tried unparenting the object so both the lattice and the object were top-level (not in a hierarchy) and origins both set to 0,0,0, so their rotation, position, scale values are identical and from the same origin. There should now be no reason this is happening yet it still behaves the same silly way.

EDIT AGAIN: It's hard to tell from my screenshots, but the lattice is NOT a perfect cube. It is more of a rhomboid or something more angular. I went into edit mode to adjust the corners to match the angle of the object, then I added more division to the U,V,W of the lattice. It seems certain that my manipulation of these control points is what the problem is, but how do I freeze the lattice so that this warped shape is considered the start shape?

Thanks for your help!
-Ben

Comment: I tried that and it does nothing different.

Comment: I noticed my object had a parent, so I unparented and tried all of the above again and it still doesn't work. (I edited this post to this effect.)

Comment: Have you made changes to lattice in *Edit mode* ? You may try to recreate lattice (if not yet). Also you may try to upload that piece with lattice and edit your post to give a link.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are using the lattice in the *exact opposite* way to how it is mathematically defined.  Put your modified lattice aside.  Create a new lattice, then apply it to your object before you modify the lattice.  Only after the two are combined should you start messing with the lattice to achieve whatever deformation you think you want.

Comment: make sure your object's and the lattice's origins are the same.

Comment: @MutantBob, I was manipulating the lattice _before_ applying because I do _not_ want the object to be deformed by the changes I made to the lattice. A good simple example is imagine that I have an object that is more or less trapezoidal in shape. I want to put a lattice on it... I would expect to be able to make a trapezoidal lattice to fit perfectly around the object and this would be the "basis" or the starting point for all deformations. It sounds like I have to leave the lattice as a cube, which is pretty limiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I went into edit mode

You should scale the lattice only in **Object mode** to encompass your object.

And yes - it doesn't need to be a cube. When you're ready with x/y/z scaling do not *Apply object transform (scale)* to the lattice at all. It will result in the same outcome.

Scaling it in edit mode is applying deformation on the object **as expected**, in your case - scaling it up/down.

Comment: I think you meant to say, "yes, it DOES need to be a cube" as it seems changing the shape from a cube to a trapezoidal shape can only be done in Edit mode, which affects the deformation.

Comment: I meant that it can be a **cuboid** as well (scaling the lattice only on a single axis in object mode). **Any** changes of the lattice in edit mode will deform the object.