# How can I slant a mesh, while keeping it the same height?

Tags: modeling

I have a box roughly like the left box in this image.

I want to be able to make it "lean" on one axis (x), without decreasing the size along the other axis (y, z) like the right box in this image.

To do it here, I moved the top face along X and then did my subdivisions.

[image]

Proportional editing almost does this, but not quite, and probably wouldn't work well on complex shapes.

[image]

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the "Shear" tool

Comment: @Gorgious That does it, thank you

Comment: Or with a lattice.

Comment: _eg_ https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/195675/15543